# Connecting my cloud build with cloud sql specifically inside the docker build

Tags: google-cloud-sql, prisma, google-workspace, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-search

Thank you in advance for your help.

I want to deploy my landing page to Cloud Run, it's a pretty basic NextJS app, there was no problem in deploying the app until I added this single API route:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "@app/lib/prisma";

const handler = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    const count = await prisma.user.findMany();
    return NextResponse.json({"count": count.length});
  }
};

export { handler as GET };
```

It's a super simple API call to get the count of my users, now the problem start when trying to build the container on Cloud Build. When I get to the stage of npm run build in this Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm run build

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=https://www.roley.me

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I get an error that I cannot connect to the database. Now I understand that you have to use the CloudSQL proxy like described here [https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-build](https://stackoverflow.com)

The problem is this is within the Docker Build, so if I use the `cloudbuild.yaml` proxy, it doesn't matter, because my Docker container is in its own environment.

On localhost this

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://<DB_USER>:<DB_PASSWORD>@<PUBLIC_IP>:<PORT>/<DB_NAME>
```

works completely fine, because my home network is on the authorized network list. Cloud Build cannot use the same URL, I presume because it's not authorized.

Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide. I've read all the threads online about this topic but all seem to be dealing with database migrations done with scripts in the source repository, while my problem is with next build itself needing to connect.

Comment: Your `connect-build` URL is broken.

Comment: @JohnHanley that is the url using a localhost authorized network. I understand when connecting via proxy you need the host parameter

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to make this setup work is by offloading the `RUN npx prisma generate` and `RUN npm run build` steps to run as a `prestart` **npm** lifecyle hook on **Cloud Run** instead of having them run on **Cloud Build**. In Cloud Run your Prisma app should be able to connect to your Cloud SQL instance using **Unix Sockets**.

When using **Cloud Run** a Unix Socket connected to a **Cloud SQL Auth Proxy** is already open in a `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` file path, you can read more about it in the [Connect with Unix Sockets section of the Connect from Cloud Run docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#node.js) here.

And here are the [Prisma docs on how to connect using Unix Sockets](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/overview/databases/postgresql#connecting-via-sockets).

With that in mind, from your specific example, your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable should look something like this when running in **Cloud Run**:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://<DB_USER>:<DB_PASSWORD>@localhost/<DB_NAME>?host=/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

The last step would be to migrate the npm build steps to run on Cloud Run, that is achievable by declaring a `prestart` script in your `package.json`, such as:

```
    "prestart": "npx prisma generate && npm run build",
```

To finalize, remove the `RUN npx prisma generate` and `RUN npm run build` lines from your Dockerfile before building again.

Comment: I had solved it, by running a cloudSQL proxy in the same RUN as npm run build;

RUN wget cloudsql && ./cloudql && npm run build

The only problem with my above approach was I had to have a credentials file within the docker container.

Thank you for pointing me in this prestart direction, this seems to be a much better solution.